# ubuntu: docker run hello-world returns an error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, proxy, x509certificate

After following the installation instructions to install docker provided in the official page I ran into the following error when I tried to run

```
docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/fc/fce289e99eb9bca977dae136fbe2a82b6b7d4c372474c9235adc1741675f587e/data?verify=1549989486-DEdrDDaoZskZzHXF84y4VY%2FxRpw%3D: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I am not finding information about solving this issue. Please note I am behind corporate proxy.
I have set the proxy in the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
```

with the following content

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyurl:8080/" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyurl:8080/"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure, your `HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyurl:8080/` ? Check that port is configured properly, it is more likely to be `443`.

Second, your proxy can work in man-in-the-middle mode, that means it establishes two separate connections: with you and with targeted server, deciphering and enciphering all traffic. In this case it signs the data it sends to you with it's own ssl certificate and you have to obtain this one and add to your trusted ones in the system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the image you are trying to pull is stored within a private registry. Have you logged to that registry?

Meanwhile, try to pull a hello-world image to check that proxy is not blocking outgoing connections from your Docker host.